# I want to customize this iframe json form

Tags: javascript, json, iframe

I want to customize this iframe form according to my style. Currently this form is coming from server. I donot know but i want to remove table tags and covert this form to bootstrap form with my own style

Here is the code that i have

```
<script src="https://www.rndframe.com/server/web/js/json.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
var srcURL= 'https://www.rndframe.com/server';
var inputOptions = {
   UserID: 'flOetnPMMYHxnsyp3plqvePWAu7jKOgptzetn/5yZ+g=',
   Style: 'STYLE3',
   FormID: 'INSTALLMENT_HUNT',
   SubID: '',
   Domain: '',
   Height: 'AUTO'
};
document.write('<scr'+'ipt type="text/javascript" src="'+
                    srcURL +'/init.php?vn=' + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(inputOptions)) + '"></scr'+'ipt>');
if(!inputOptions.TargetDivID){document.write('<di'+'v id="rsForm"></di'+'v>');}
</script>
```

Comment: What is the actual question? What iframe? What html? Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Through this code a form is appeared on the web page. Simple i want to customize this form according to my requirements.